# GChart on GAE wont show

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, gchart

I am using Eclipse with GAE on a MacBook Pro with GChart. My problem is that I cant get any chart to show when I am developing, but when I use regular tools such as Buttons or Labels with GAE they work just fine. The code doesn't give me any errors, so I am assuming that I have the right code:

```
public class TestingTesting implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        GChart graf = new GChart();
        graf.setTitle("testing");
        graf.setChartSize(200, 200);
        graf.addCurve();
        graf.getCurve().getSymbol().setFillThickness(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            graf.getCurve().addPoint(i,i*i);
        Button btnOk = new Button("Ok");
        RootPanel.get("chartdiv").add(graf);
        RootPanel.get("button").add(btnOk);
    }
}
```

and my TestingTesting.gwt.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='testingtesting'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet. You can change -->
    <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting -->
    <!-- any one of the following lines. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/> -->
    <!-- Other module inherits -->
    <inherits name='com.googlecode.gchart.GChart' />
    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='test.gchart.sollution.client.TestingTesting' />
    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />
</module>
```

My TestingTesting.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


<title>Chart Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="testingtesting/testingtesting.nocache.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    <div id="button"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

other than that, my structure of the project in Eclipse is

```
 /
 - gchart.jar
 - App Engine SDK [App Engine 1.3.5]
 - GWT SDK [GWT - 2.0.4]
 - JRE System Library
 - src
 -- test.gchart.sollution
 --- TestingTesting.gwt.xml
 -- test.gchart.sollution.client
 --- TestingTesting.java
 -- test.gchart.sollution.server
 -- test.gchart.sollution.shared
 --- FieldVerifier.java 
 - META-INF
 -- jdoconfig.xml
 - log4j.properties
 - war
 -- TestTest.html
 - WEB-INF
 -- appengine-web.xml
 -- logging.properties
 -- web.xml
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what the problem might be? The button shows without any problem, but the chart doesn't?

Comment: Might be helpful to include a link to the library you're using: http://code.google.com/p/clientsidegchart -- might also be useful to ask the developers of that library, who may have a better understanding of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figuered out what I've made wrong.
 
I forgot on the TestingTesting.java to include

```
RootPanel.get("chartdiv").add(graf); 
graf.update();      // you have to update your graph before it renders
```